# Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection injects null to constructor instead of throwing an exception when service is missing

Tags: c#, .net, azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

Microsoft DI for Azure Functions using 3.0 works quite surprisingly.
It injects null if service is not located instead of throwing an exception. It happens only for sub-dependencies (not root), in below case, if any parameter of `OutboxRelay` constructor is missing, DI resolves it as null instead of throwing an exception that service is not registered.

I have a following Azure Function 3.0 :

```
public class OutboxRelayFunction
{
    private readonly IOutboxRelay _outboxRelay;

    public OutboxRelayFunction(IOutboxRelay outboxRelay)
    {
        _outboxRelay = outboxRelay;
    }

    [FunctionName("OutboxRelay")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("*/1 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
    }
}
```

I've configured DI using Microsoft's container:

```
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

    [assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
    namespace Outbox.Relay
    {
        public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
        {
            public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
            {
                 builder.Services.AddScoped<IOutboxRelay, OutboxRelay>();
                 builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBusClient, ServiceBusClient>();
            }
        }
    }
```

OutboxRelay constructor:

```
public class OutboxRelay : IOutboxRelay
{
    private readonly IOutboxManager _outboxManager;
    private readonly IBusClient _busClient;
    private readonly ILogger<OutboxRelay> _logger;

    public OutboxRelay(IOutboxManager outboxManager,
        IBusClient busClient,
        ILogger<OutboxRelay> logger)
    {
        _outboxManager = outboxManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(outboxManager));
        _busClient = busClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(busClient));
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }
}
```

[image: Debugging]

As you can see, instead of throwing an exception while trying to create `OutboxRelay` instance it simply injects null to `IOutboxManager` which is not registered in DI. Can I change the default behaviour so that exception will be thrown when trying to resolve an instance of `OutboxRelay` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.

Since `IOutboxManager` is `reference type`, it's ok to define something like `IOutboxManager outboxManager = null`. Then in the constructor `public OutboxRelay(IOutboxManager outboxManager,xxx)`, it's ok to pass `null` for the parameter `outboxManager` regardless of the `IOutboxManager` is registered in DI or not. You should always use `?? operator` to determine throwing an error or not.

Comment: No, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection would normally throw if the dependency is missing (unless the parameter has a default value). But Azure Functions actually uses a different IoC container, DryIoC, which doesn't behave the same as Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.